# Can you `source` the `ipython profile` (Jupyter) while in a notebook?

Tags: ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

The iPython profile or Jupyter profile path: `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/startup.ipy`

I update this quite often.

**Is there a way to `source` this within a notebook** like when you're in the terminal and `source ~/.bash_profile` after you make an update?  My current method is to close the kernel and Jupyter session then restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [%run](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html?highlight=magics#magic-run) to do this:

```
%run ~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/startup.ipy
```

If you do `%run -i [script]`, then your current interactive namespace will be available to the script.

Comment: You have no idea how much time that's gonna save me! Thanks